# psycopg2 psycopg2.InternalError dependent objects

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using peewee on heroku, but according to peewee docs, dropping related tables has to be done in code.

Question is how?

I have the following models

```
class WebPage(Model):
  title = CharField()

class Term(Model):
  name = CharField()

class WebPageTerms(Model):
  term = ForeignKeyField(Term)
  webpage = ForeignKeyField(WebPage)
```

Drop table method that includes the postgresql custom statement:

```
def drop_tables():
   WebPage.drop_table(fail_silently=True)
   Term.drop_table(fail_silently=True)
   WebPageTerms.drop_table(fail_silently=True)
```

as part of the deployment I drop all tables and create them in order to get new fields added.

I have tried the following approach but it's still not working:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='' user='' host='' password=''")
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute("DROP table webpageterms CASCADE")
curr.execute("DROP table webpage CASCADE")
curr.close()
conn.close()
```

but I keep getting the same error

> psycopg2.InternalError: cannot drop table webpage because other
>   objects depend on it DETAIL:  constraint webpageterms_webpage_id_fkey
>   on table webpageterms depends on table webpage HINT:  Use DROP ...
>   CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

how can I drop these tables?

** EDIT **
Tried to change the code to:

```
curr.execute("ALTER TABLE webpageterms DROP CONSTRAINT webpageterms_webpage_id_fkey")
```

but I am getting:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: cannot drop table webpage because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint webpageterms_webpage_id_fkey on table webpageterms depends on table webpage
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop them in this order:

```
WebPageTerms.drop_table(fail_silently=True)
Term.drop_table(fail_silently=True)
WebPage.drop_table(fail_silently=True)
```

Peewee comes with a helper to drop tables -- it sorts them topologically for you by following foreign keys:

```
from peewee import drop_model_tables
drop_model_tables([WebPage, Term, WebPageTerms])  # <-- will sort them correctly
```

Comment: For anyone using more recent versions of peewee see: [`Database.drop_tables`](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/3.4.0/peewee/api.html?highlight=drop_tables#Database.drop_tables)

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the constraints on the foreign keys first:

> `ALTER TABLE "webpageterms" DROP CONSTRAINT "webpageterms_webpage_id_fkey"`

and (although I don't know the exact name of the foreign key here, because it isn't listed)

> `ALTER TABLE "webpageterms" DROP CONSTRAINT "webpageterms_term_id_fkey"`

Comment: Dropping the constraint will fix the problem, but it can be more easily solved by dropping them in a different order.